# jQuery plug-in and variable scope

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've developed a simple plug-in that allows you to create a multi-column dropdown for a text box. You pass in a web service URL, and an array of jQuery selectors that corresponds to each element you would like populated from each column in the result set.

$('#txtProduct').multiColumnDropDown({
            'url': '/api/GetProductAndCategoryByRegion',
            'targets' : ['#txtProduct', "#txtCategory"]
        });

This will build a multi-column dropdown, and when the user clicks a record in it, #txtProduct and #txtCategory get populated.

Everything works as it should, but I want to be able to apply multiple multiColumnDropDowns to my page. I'm going to run into issues in that I don't know how to reference the dynamically-generated dropdown markup specific to an instance of the plugin.

In my plug-in, I generate a wrapper for the dropdown and position it where needed. If I want to update the wrapper and its dropdown by re-querying, how do I ensure I only update the one I want, and not all the wrappers I have generated?

Complete code below:

```
(function ($) {
var methods = {
    init: function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var settings = $.extend({
                'targets': [this]
            }, options);

            var targets = settings["targets"];

            var yOffset = $(this).position().top + $(this).height() + 'px';
            var xOffset = $(this).position().left + 'px';

            var wrapper = $('<div class="dropdown-wrapper"></div>')
                .css('top', yOffset)
                .css('left', xOffset)
                .hide();

            $(document).click(function () {
                wrapper.hide();
            })

            if (settings["url"] != undefined && settings["url"] != '') {
                methods.populateDropDown(settings["url"], targets, wrapper);
            }

            $(this).click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                wrapper.show();
            });
        });
    },
    update: function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var settings = $.extend({
                'targets': [this]
            }, options);

            var targets = settings["targets"];

            //How do I reference the correct wrapper?
            //The following will reference all wrappers on the page :\
            var wrapper = $('div.dropdown-wrapper')

            //Repopulate the wrapper and dropdown code goes here....
        })
    },
    populateDropDown: function (url, targets, wrapper) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var $table = $('<table class="multi-column-table">');
            data.forEach(function (item) {
                var $tr = $('<tr>').appendTo($table);
                var idx = 0;
                $.each(item, function (k, v) {
                    var $td = $('<td>');
                    if (targets[idx] != undefined)
                        $td.attr('data-target', targets[idx]);
                    $td.text(v);
                    $td.appendTo($tr);
                    idx++;
                });
            });
            $table.on('click', 'tr', function () {
                $.each(this.children, function (i, td) {
                    if ($(td).attr('data-target'))
                        $($(td).attr('data-target')).val($(td).text());
                });
            });
            $(wrapper).append($table).prependTo('body');

        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
        });
    }
};

$.fn.multiColumnDropDown = function (method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.multiColumnDropDown');
    }
};
```

})(jQuery);

And in case any one is interested in the CSS:

```
.dropdown-wrapper
{
border:1px solid #000;
border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
z-index:100;
background-color:#fff;
position:absolute;
}

.dropdown-wrapper tr:hover
{
background-color:#0081C2;
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this guide Jquery Plugin Authoring (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Basically, you need to store the instance of the plugin to the data attribute of the html control. Check the code below

```
 var $this = $(this),
         data = $this.data('tooltip'),
         tooltip = $('<div />', {
           text : $this.attr('title')
         });

     // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
     if ( ! data ) {

       /*
         Do more setup stuff here
       */

       $(this).data('tooltip', {
           target : $this,
           tooltip : tooltip
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

`var wrapper = $('div.dropdown-wrapper')` within the `update` method references all the wrappers on the page, like you noticed, because you are selecting all the divs with the `dropdown-wrapper` class.

To reference the wrapper created in that instance, you have to store the wrapper created in the `init` function somewhere. For this, you can use the [data](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data) method on the plugin context.